# Membership Types not translated on default Contribution page "Member sign up"

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contribution-page, translation

On CiviCRM 5.43.2 in WordPress, I have 2 Membership Types a user can sign up to.

All other text on the form is translated except for the "Membership Types Label" and  "Membership Types". These appear in English on both English and French versions of the site.

The field "Membership Types Label" lacks an icon that you would usually click to open a form to enter the translations for other languages, as if this field is not available for translation.

I have added a translation for the Membership Type name in the Membership component.

Is there a way to translate these fields, or could this be a bug with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Member Sign Up form shows options for the different available memberships but these do not get translated.

There is the option to create a price set for these fields, and this opens up new options including translating labels.

Answer (score 1):

My multilingual install of Drupal + CiviCRM 5.35.2 does allow translations (assuming you're on a page url like this: /en/civicrm/admin/member/membershipType/add?action=update&id=1&reset=1)

So maybe it's a recent regression. There has been some recent work on membership as I recall.

On the other hand, most of the times these fields would be exposed would be in a fieldset, so perhaps that's where you'd want to translate them anyway?

Comment: *On the other hand, most of the times these fields would be exposed would be in a fieldset, so perhaps that's where you'd want to translate them anyway?*


Yes you are right. By default, the Member Sign Up form shows options for the different available memberships but there is also an option to transform the fields into price sets. I have done this now and this has given me new options to translate the fields I previously could not translate.